# (System)Verilog: extracting a smaller bus/vector from a larger bus?

Tags: digital-logic, verilog, hdl, system-verilog

What is the best practice for creating a bus, which is just extraction of certain bits of a larger bus. I do not want to store the index numbers to make the lookup in the generate-for if it could be avoided....I was hoping for something like following code which is of course not valid. Can we take advantage of the fact somehow that the extracted shorter bus is always consecutive bits from the larger bus?

```
localparam logic [7:0] VALID = {1'b0, 1'b1, 1'b1, 1'b1, 1'b1, 1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0}; 


 genvar m, j;
  generate
    for (m=0; m<8; m++) begin
      if (VALID[m]) begin
        assign short_bus[j] = large_bus[m];
        j++;
      end
  endgenerate
```

Comment: Do you know in advance which bits are going to be valid? If so, you could just use `assign short_bus = VALID[6:3];` - although I don't think that's what you're asking...

Comment: VALID only tells which bits of the large_bus go onto the short_bus

Comment: Think hardware instead of Verilog. The dumbest way is a set of multiplexers. The smartest way is shift register (but will require a number of cycles).

Comment: @Anonymous, the smartest way is just connect to the wires you want to connect to and not the other wires. No register involved (and OP doesn't seem to want the signals syncronized to a clock the way a register-based solution would require)

Comment: @frank_010, if the wanted bits are always consecutive why not just use
`assign short_bus[4:0] = large_bus[first_index+4:first_index];` ?
Sorry I don't know enough SystemVerilog to make this a full answer.

Comment: @ThePhoton OP wants to get a vector of wires market as "valid". Currently it is defined vector, but if it is dynamic there will be a need to scan through this vector.

Comment: @Anonymous, but they define which bits are valid in a parameter, not an input or output. So it should be known at compile time, not dynamic. And in the question text they state an additional assumption that the valid bits are consecutive, without which my suggestion won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use an array with the length of the short bus that maps short bus indices to large bus ones:

```
// Large Bus Width
localparam int LBW = 8;
localparam logic [LBW-1:0] VALID = {1'b0, 1'b1, 1'b1, 1'b1, 1'b1, 1'b0, 1'b0, 1'b0};

// 1. Function returning the width of the short bus
function automatic int get_short_width();
    automatic int si = 0;
    for (int li=0; li<LBW; li++)
        if (VALID[li])
            si++;
    return si;
endfunction

// Short Bus Width
localparam int SBW = get_short_width();

typedef int t_idx_arr[SBW];
// 2. Function returing the large-to-short array index mapping
function automatic t_idx_arr get_short_indices();
    t_idx_arr idx_ret;
    automatic int si = 0;

    for (int li=0; li<LBW; li++) begin
        if (VALID[li]) begin
            idx_ret[si] = li;
            si++;
        end
    end
    return idx_ret;
endfunction

// Large 2 Short Index Array
localparam t_idx_arr L2S_IDX = get_short_indices();

// 3. Assign
logic[LBW-1:0] large_bus;
logic[SBW-1:0] short_bus;

// note: loop on the SHORT bus width!
for (genvar si=0; si<SBW; si++) begin
    assign short_bus[si] = large_bus[L2S_IDX[si]];
end

assign large_bus = 8'b1101_1011;
// short_bus = 4'b1011
```

This works for non-consecutive valid bit positions on the large bus as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options in SystemVerilog.

If your busses are nets, you can use an `alias` construct (See section 10.11 of the 1800-2017 LRM)

```
alias long_bus[M:N] = short_bus;
alias long_bus[O:+W] = short_bus;
```

`M,N,O`, and `W` must all be constant expressions of literals or parameters.
For variables or nets, you can use the `let` construct (See section 11.12)

```
let short_bus = long_bus[M:N];
let short_bus = long_bus[O+:W]; // O does not need to be a constant
```

The benefits of these constructs over the `assign` construct is that its possible to use `short_bus` on both the LHS and RHS of an assignment.